# installing insoshi in rails 4 with ruby 1.9.3 in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, social-networking, ruby-1.9.3, insoshi

I am trying to use Insoshi in Rails 4 and everything works fine until the `$ script/install`. Whenever I put this command in my command prompt I get this error:

> 'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am new to rails and want to try Insoshi. Please help if you can. I am using Rails 4.0.0 with Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage ruby `script/install` is present in Rails 2.3.x versions and older.

If you look into the `script/install` file in `insoshi` https://github.com/insoshi/insoshi/blob/master/script/install

you can see below commands

```
system("rake gems:install")
# Install the gem dependencies (if any).
system("sudo rake gems:install")
# Create the databases.
system("rake db:create:all")
# Run the main install task.
system("rake install")
```

So you can run those commands

`cd insoshi` 
   `bundle exec rake db:create`
   `bundle exec rake install`

Comment: Thanks sir for the help but when i put the `rake gems:install` i get another error `C:\Sites\insoshi>rake gems:install
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined method `path' for class `ActionController::UploadedStringIO
'` and so on.